# Perforce: How do you integrate, safe resolve, and submit programatically between branches in CI

Tags: shell, grep, continuous-integration, perforce

I'd like to create a script that runs in CI on a cadence that integrates, safe resolves, and submits my master branch into my dev branch in order to keep the dev branch updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following commands:

- integrate: `p4 integrate`
- safe resolve: `p4 resolve -as`
- submit: `p4 submit`

Executing these commands in CI depends on your CI framework.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a script based on your answer Samwise. This script reverts and deletes the changelist if the submit fails, since the manual merge must be done by a different user on a different workspace outside the CI

```
echo "**** Integrating"
p4 integrate //master/branch/... //dev/branch/...
echo "**** Safe Resolving"
p4 resolve -as
echo "**** Submitting"
touch output.txt
p4 submit -d "Nightly merge from Master to Dev Stream" 2>&1 | tee output.txt
echo "**** output.txt"
cat output.txt
RESULT=$(grep ".*Submit failed -- fix problems above then use.*" output.txt)
echo "**** Grep error RESULT: $RESULT"
if [ -n "$RESULT" ]; then
# example line
# [08:00:32][Step 1/1] Submit failed -- fix problems above then use 'p4 submit -c 27831'.
CL=$(grep ".*Submit failed.*p4 submit -c.*" output.txt | sed -n "s/^.*c \([0-9]*\)'\./\1/p")
echo "**** Changelist to revert and delete: $CL"
echo "**** Revert Changelist"
p4 revert -c "$CL" //...
echo "**** Delete Changelist"
p4 change -d "$CL"
exit 1
fi
```